# Strange behaviour in Knockout custom binding with jQuery slideUp/slideDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I need to control some collapsable panels with Knockout (the number of panels is variable, but it doesn't change during the session).

I have set the panel status (open/close) in an array of booleans and I use a custom binding to show/hide the panel with jQuery animation:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.collapse = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        if (valueAccessor()) {
            $(element).slideDown();
        } else {
            $(element).slideUp();
        }
    }
};
```

If I define the array in this way everythings works:

```
myModel.collapseOpened = ko.observableArray([
    ko.observable(true),
    ko.observable(false),
    ko.observable(false)
]);
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zonia3000/7MaAt/2/)

But I don't need all of this observable, so I would define the array in this way:

```
myModel.collapseOpened = ko.observable([
    true,false,false
]);
```

But if I do this jQuery has a strange behaviour: the `display: none` is set and unset but without animation, except for the `slideup()` **on the last panel** (!!!)

[(Not) Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zonia3000/7MaAt/3/)

Can everybody explain me **why**? Thanks!

Comment: Please have a look at my tab's example here https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bindings/blob/master/src/knockout.bindings.js#L235 It's a more MVVM way of solving this. It can easily be converted into the slidedown

Comment: Try the demo here http://jsfiddle.net/H8xWY/130/

Comment: `valueAccessor()` will give you the observable. `valueAccessor()()` would be required to get the value inside.

Answer (score 0):

Knockout will only register changes on observable values. You don't need all the nested observables, the values in an observableArray are automatically acted upon. The following works perfectly.

```
myModel.collapseOpened = ko.observableArray([ true,false,false ]);
```

You **cannot** use an observable to store an array, hence that's why observableArrays exist...

Comment: Sorry but this works "bad" as my second example. Try the fiddles. The problem is with jQuery. Using the observable the update function is called but jQuery respond "bad" (with a not smooth animation).

Comment: @xonya, ah ok I get you now. I'll update my answer shortly :)